# Getting compilation error in boost 1_53

Tags: macos, boost

I am trying to compile an existing application with boost 1_53 on Mac OS X. I am getting lots of errors in boost files. Same thing I tried in Windows 7 using VS 2010 it is working fine. But on Mac OS X 10.7  I am getting errors. I tried on both Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 and LLVM GCC 4.2.

**1.has_binary_operator.hpp**
`Library/boost/include/boost_1_53/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp
parse issue   Expected expression`

**2. lexical_cast.hpp**
`No member named 'value' in 'boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<char>, unsigned short, boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::dont_care>'`

Am I missing something?

Comment: What compiler (and compiler version) are you using ? And what is MAx OS ?

Comment: @PaulR Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 even I tried in  LLVM GCC 2 as well.It is not working.

Comment: OK - so did you mean **Mac OS X** ?

Comment: OK - for future reference you can use the `edit` button above to clean up your question and fix the typos etc.

Comment: @PaulR sure I will do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30535/discussion-between-chris-vr-and-paul-r)

Comment: Boost 1.52.0 works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.8. Since you're running a relatively old version of Mac OS X and old compilers you might want to consider an earlier version of boost?